# Не работает drag&drop в Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text, ubuntu

С некоторого времени пробую работать в Sublime Text 2. Довольно удобный редактор. Однако встретил одну проблему: невозможно мышкой перетащить выделенный текст. Это при том, что официально в версии 2 эта возможность добавлена. Нет ли у кого-нибудь такой же проблемы и как ее можно победить (если вообще возможно)?

Sublime Text 2.0.1 64 bit, Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64

**P.S.** В Windows XP работает нормально.

Comment: У меня не работает тоже - 12.04 64bit в Sublime Text 2.0.1 Стало интересно, а в каких случаях это может применяться? Помоему нет ничего лучше ctrl+c/ctrl+v

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> Settings-User:

```
{
    ...
    "drag_text": true,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Такая запись уже имеется в Settings-Default, однако толку никакого.

Comment: А в Settings-User или SyntaxSpecific-User они не перекрываются?

Answer (score 0):

В `Preferences.sublime-settings` сказано на счёт `drag_text`:

```
When drag_text is enabled, clicking on selected text will begin a
drag-drop operation. This is not currently implemented under Linux.
```

Эта фича не работает в линуксах!